# Loading style from GeoPackage with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis-3, geopackage, qml

Reading the [documentation](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html#a8b271b8bf3074e84808cff26f722b26f) I do not understand how the the row in layer_styles is specified (and why a table name has to be given)...

```py
layer.loadNamedStyleFromDatabase('/path/to/geopackage/','layer_styles', 'styleName')
```

... doesn't do the trick.

Comment: It seems this method doesn't accept three parameters:TypeError: QgsMapLayer.loadNamedStyleFromDatabase(): too many arguments

Comment: Only db and uri loadNamedStyleFromDatabase(self, db: str, uri: str) → Tuple[bool, str] see python doc here:https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Map/QgsMapLayer.html?highlight=loadnamedstylefromdatabase#qgis.core.QgsMapLayer.loadNamedStyleFromDatabase

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to load the default style of the layer [here][1] (for PostGIS) and it's working on a geopackage. (For QGIS 3.X version (3.14 tested))

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtXml import QDomDocument

layer = iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()
listedStyles = layer.listStylesInDatabase()
numberOfStyles = listedStyles[0]
defaultStyleId = listedStyles[1][0]
# defaultStyleName = listedStyles[2][0]
# defaultStyleDate = listedStyles[3][0]
if numberOfStyles > 0:
    styledoc = QDomDocument()
    styleTuple = layer.getStyleFromDatabase(defaultStyleId)
    styleqml = styleTuple[0]
    styledoc.setContent(styleqml)
    layer.importNamedStyle(styledoc)
    layer.triggerRepaint()
```

If you want a spécific style, you can find it in the tuple of lists made by layer.listStylesInDatabase() that is returning:

- first, the number of styles linked to your layer and saved in the geopackage;
- the list of styles' id;
- the list of styles' name;
- the list of styles' date;
  you have to iterate over the list of styles' name, then pick the style's id you need.

  ```
    from qgis.PyQt.QtXml import QDomDocument    
    layer = iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()
    listedStyles = layer.listStylesInDatabase()
    numberOfStyles = listedStyles[0]
    if numberOfStyles > 0:
        i = 0
        for name in listedStyles[2]:
            if name == "buildings_old":
                styleId = listedStyles[1][i]
                styledoc = QDomDocument()
                styleTuple = layer.getStyleFromDatabase(styleId)
                styleqml = styleTuple[0]
                styledoc.setContent(styleqml)
                layer.importNamedStyle(styledoc)
                layer.triggerRepaint()
            i+=1


  [1]: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91429/pyqgis-loading-layer-style-with-postgis/371589#371589
  ```